# Syntax Error: Call Member Function Pointer using Pointer to Object

Tags: c++, pointers, delegates

I have a tricky syntax error which I cannot figure out. I am trying to run a function delegate where the context is a pointer to an object.

Syntax error:

```
((object)->*(ptrToMember)) // the compiler doesn't like the ->*
```

> Where `object` is of the type `Component*`
>
> And `ptrToMember` is of the type `void (Component::*EventCallback) ()`

Below is the code with the syntax error:

```
typedef void (Component::*EventCallback) ();

...

std::weak_ptr<Component> wc( mySharedPtr );
EventCallback ec = &Component::run;

((wc.lock())->*(ec))(); // syntax error
(wc.lock()->(*ec))(); // simpler version but still syntax error

// This is ok, but is there any significant time or memory involved in this reference object creation?
Component& wcc = *wc.lock();
(wcc.*ec)();
```

Comment: Too lazy to search for the duplicate of this so here `(object->*ptrToMember)()`

Comment: Wow, so many redundant parentheses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wc.lock()` returns a `std::shared_ptr<Component>` but you are expecting it to return a raw `Component*` pointer instead.  You cannot call the `->*` on the `std::shared_ptr` itself. You have to ask it for the `Component*` pointer it is holding, and then you can use the `->*` operator on that pointer, eg:

```
(wc.lock().get()->*ec)();
```

Since you are dealing with a `std::weak_ptr`, which could expire before you use it, you should make sure the `Component` object is actually available after locking before you try to access it:

```
if (auto sptr = wc.lock()) {
    (sptr.get()->*ec)();
}
else {
    // wc had expired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `wc.lock()` is a `shared_ptr`. This is one of the few cases where the smart pointer diverges from a dumb pointer. `shared_ptr` does not implement `operator ->*`, so your first syntax can't work. (It's not a syntax error, you're just trying to do something `shared_ptr` doesn't support.)

You've found a workaround though.